# Can you have a "pointer to member" to a member of a union?

Tags: c++

All descriptions that I can find talk about "pointer to member" in the context of a class. Unions are very similar to structures, and in particular have members too. Can you have a pointer to those members too?

E.g.

```
union x {
    int a;
    float b;
};
int x::*p = &x::a;
```

I'm not talking about pointer to the union as a whole, pointers as members of a union, etc. `p` in the example above would really be an offset, obviously of size 0. I'd need this construct to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375558/select-an-union-member-depending-on-a-template-parameter).

Comment: Unions *are* classes (§9/5), so I guess "yes".

Comment: that code compiles so I assume yes

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want it, though. You can cast `&x` to `int *` to access `a` without needing to know its name.

Comment: Unions are class *types* per the standard, so yes, so long as they are not bit-field members, you should be in the clear.

Comment: Are you going to use those member-pointers as template arguments?: :-)

Comment: Note, using union PTM non-type template arguments is just a roundabout way of using type template arguments and casting the address of the union.

Comment: Yeah - union PTMs are really a very degenerate thing: They all have the same value, and their only purpose is static, i.e. it is their *type*. That reflects the fact that it doesn't make sense to have more than one union member of the same type. (Chew on that, France.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

§3.9.2/1: Compound types can be constructed in the following ways: … pointers to non-static 50 class members, which identify members of a given type within objects of a given class,

§8.3.3/1: In a declaration T D where D has the form … and the *nested-name-specifier* denotes a class, …

§5.3.1/3: The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`, the result has type “pointer to member of class C of type T” and is a prvalue designating `C::m`.

And of course §9.5/5: A *union* is a class defined with the class-key `union`…

(§3.9.2/1 also mentions: *unions*, which are classes…)

No mention that the class cannot be a union, so yes, you can form such a PTM type and value.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how equality is defined among such objects. Do they all compare equal to `nullptr`?

Comment: A pointer to the first member of a struct doesn't compare equal to `nullptr` even if its offset is 0. A pointer to a member of a union shouldn't either.

Comment: … According to GCC they are all equal to each other but not zero.

Comment: @hvd the offset doesn't have to enter into it. There are not alternative values at all, not even the possibility of asking what the offset is. But, it appears that GCC implements and uses the offset anyway, so dereferencing union PTM null results in wonky UB.

Comment: You can have values of either `&x::a`, or `nullptr`. That's two distinct values. :) And `nullptr` is implemented as a magic impossible offset value (-1, IIRC), so the offset is relevant for GCC.